# Understanding how to calculate the total with variable assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and trying to get a head start on my class next semester. I am trying to show the total cost and then print it. Where am I going wrong?

```
print('Would you like a rental car?')
rental = (input('Yes or No? '))
    if rental.lower() == yes:
        car = float(input('Dollar Amount?'))
    else:
        print('Thank You!')


print('Would you need a flight?')
flight = (input('Yes or No '))
    if flight.lower() == yes:
        plane = float(input('Dollar Amount? '))
    else:
        print('Thank You!')

print('Would need a hotel?')
hotel = (input('Yes or No? '))
    if hotel.lower() == yes:
        room = float(input('Dollar Amount? '))



sum = travel (room + plane + car)
print('This is the total amount that it may cost you, ' + travel  '!')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You provided the code and what you expect it to do, and that's a good start. Please also describe the issue that you're having (including full stack trace if you have one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem 1

Fix your indentation. Python uses indentation to define what block code is executed in (i.e. in an `if` statement, or after it). Here's what you should do:

- Select all (cmd / ctrl + a), and then keep pressing (cmd / ctrl + [) to de-indent. Do this until nothing is indented.
- On any line you want in an if / else statement, press the TAB key at the start of that line.

### Problem 2

The `input` function (which gets user input) returns a string. You then try to compare this to an undefined variable `yes`. Replace the `yes` in your `if` statements with `"yes"` or `'yes'` to ensure you are comparing two strings.

### Problem 3

Remember to end **all** of your strings, with a closing quotation mark. You forgot one printing "Thank You" after the "Would you need a flight?" question.

Replace: `print('Thank you.)` with `print('Thank you.')`

### Problem 4

Second-to-last line, you define `sum`, which is never used. Then, you try to use the undefined `travel` function to add up your three variables. This line of code, in general, makes no sense. I am assuming that you meant this:

```
travel = (room + plane + car)
```

### Problem 5

You can't concat floats / ints to strings.

This should be the final line:

```
print('This is the total amout that it is may cost you, '+str(travel)+'!')
```

Also, you forgot the concat operator (`+`) when appending the exclamation mark.

### Final Code:

Here is the working version of your code:

```
print('Would you like a rental car?')
rental = (input('Yes or No? '))
if rental.lower() == 'yes':
    car = float(input('Dollar Amount?'))
else:
    print('Thank You!')


print('Would you need a flight?')
flight = (input('Yes or No '))
if flight.lower() == 'yes':
    plane = float(input('Dollar Amount? '))
else:
    print('Thank You!')

print('Would need a hotel?')
hotel = (input('Yes or No? '))
if hotel.lower() == 'yes':
    room = float(input('Dollar Amount? '))



travel = (room + plane + car)
print('This is the total amout that it is may cost you, ' + str(travel)+  '!')
```

### Recommendations:

This works, but it could be better. Here are a few recommendations, which will help you not only with this project, but also with further ones:

- You can combine your `print` and `input` functions together, since `input` basically prints and then waits for input. To format it like you have now, simply include a newline character, `\n`. For example, instead of

  ```
  print('Would you like a rental car?')
  rental = (input('Yes or No? '))
  ```

  you could do

  ```
  rental = input("Would you like a rental car?\nYes or No?")
  ```
- These lines could actually be simplified further. You don't need to define the variable `rental`, but instead you can just use its' output directly in the `if` statement, i.e.

  ```
  if input("Would you like a rental care?\nYes or No?").lower() == "yes" :
      ...
  ```
- Learn to use `try` / `catch` statements to catch errors. When entering the amount for a travel expense, the user has to type a number. But what if they type a string instead? Your program would crash. Learn how to use `try` / `catch` statements to prevent this from happening (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

There's not really much apart from that. These were all just beginners mistakes, and soon you'll be writing good code that works well :D

I was also impressed to see how you handled the "yes" / "no" user input by converting the answers to lower case and then checking them, which is something that a lot of people of your skill level neglect to do.

Comment: Thank you, I learn a lot from your feed back. One thing I am still a little confused about is the indentation. The book I read stated to set the tab to space 4, but it seem that many are say I need to fix it. What is the proper spacing?

Comment: Hi! Glad I could help :D You can set your tabs to any amount of spaces that you want, however what matters is what lines you indent, and by how many "tabs". This article (http://www.annedawson.net/Python_Spaces_Indentation.html) should clear things up, but feel free to ask me more if you've got more questions.